# Finding total time when one or two plants are available at same time

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table containing shutdown events for two plants in the below format:

```
ID  Shutdown_Start     Shutdown_End     Plant  DayCode Event_Description
```

```
1   2017-03-01 06:00   017-03-01 15:00  2      1        AA
2   2017-03-01 09:00   017-03-01 20:00  1      1        BB
3   2017-03-02 08:00   017-03-02 19:00  2      2        CC
4   2017-03-06 13:00   017-03-06 23:00  1      6        DD
5   2017-03-20 09:00   017-03-21 06:00  2      20       EE
6   2017-03-23 06:00   017-03-24 06:00  1      23       FF
7   2017-03-23 06:00   017-03-23 22:00  2      23       GG
```

The DayCode column represents a special code for each day starting from 06:00 to 06:00 next day.
What I need to do is to calculate total time in month where any one of both plants was running or the two of them running at the same time. I need to now total time I am receiving an input feed whether to both plants or any one of them.

In the above table I can have multiple events per day for each plant.

Below is actual data for December 2017 where the value of no of hours where at least one of plants not shutdown is 685.85 hours while the updated query below will show 528 hours. To give more explanation, in this case Plant 14 was shutdown all the month, while Plant 15 was shutdown for different periods for total of 58.15 hours so for the rest of the month I have at least one plant running. The calculation shall be 31*24 - 58.15 = 685.85.

```
EventID DayCode Plant   START               FINISH
```

```
76093   4516    14  2017-12-01 06:00:00.000 2017-12-02 06:00:00.000
76098   4516    15  2017-12-01 15:30:00.000 2017-12-02 06:00:00.000
76099   4517    14  2017-12-02 06:00:00.000 2017-12-03 06:00:00.000
76101   4517    15  2017-12-02 06:00:00.000 2017-12-03 06:00:00.000
76106   4518    14  2017-12-03 06:00:00.000 2017-12-04 06:00:00.000
76127   4518    15  2017-12-03 06:00:00.000 2017-12-03 17:40:00.000
76112   4519    14  2017-12-04 06:00:00.000 2017-12-05 06:00:00.000
76117   4520    14  2017-12-05 06:00:00.000 2017-12-06 06:00:00.000
76122   4521    14  2017-12-06 06:00:00.000 2017-12-07 06:00:00.000
76128   4522    14  2017-12-07 06:00:00.000 2017-12-08 06:00:00.000
76133   4523    14  2017-12-08 06:00:00.000 2017-12-09 06:00:00.000
76138   4524    14  2017-12-09 06:00:00.000 2017-12-10 06:00:00.000
76151   4525    14  2017-12-10 06:00:00.000 2017-12-11 06:00:00.000
76155   4526    14  2017-12-11 06:00:00.000 2017-12-12 06:00:00.000
76159   4527    14  2017-12-12 06:00:00.000 2017-12-13 06:00:00.000
76163   4528    14  2017-12-13 06:00:00.000 2017-12-14 06:00:00.000
76168   4529    14  2017-12-14 06:00:00.000 2017-12-15 06:00:00.000
76172   4530    14  2017-12-15 06:00:00.000 2017-12-16 06:00:00.000
76176   4531    14  2017-12-16 06:00:00.000 2017-12-17 06:00:00.000
76180   4532    14  2017-12-17 06:00:00.000 2017-12-18 06:00:00.000
76184   4533    14  2017-12-18 06:00:00.000 2017-12-19 06:00:00.000
76188   4534    14  2017-12-19 06:00:00.000 2017-12-20 06:00:00.000
76192   4535    14  2017-12-20 06:00:00.000 2017-12-21 06:00:00.000
76196   4536    14  2017-12-21 06:00:00.000 2017-12-22 06:00:00.000
76199   4537    14  2017-12-22 06:00:00.000 2017-12-23 06:00:00.000
76202   4538    14  2017-12-23 06:00:00.000 2017-12-24 06:00:00.000
76205   4539    14  2017-12-24 06:00:00.000 2017-12-25 06:00:00.000
76207   4540    14  2017-12-25 06:00:00.000 2017-12-26 06:00:00.000
76209   4541    14  2017-12-26 06:00:00.000 2017-12-27 06:00:00.000
76211   4542    14  2017-12-27 06:00:00.000 2017-12-28 06:00:00.000
76213   4543    14  2017-12-28 06:00:00.000 2017-12-29 06:00:00.000
76215   4544    14  2017-12-29 06:00:00.000 2017-12-30 06:00:00.000
76217   4545    14  2017-12-30 06:00:00.000 2017-12-31 01:00:00.000
76221   4545    15  2017-12-30 11:58:00.000 2017-12-30 12:57:00.000
76218   4545    14  2017-12-31 01:00:00.000 2017-12-31 06:00:00.000
76223   4545    15  2017-12-31 01:30:00.000 2017-12-31 06:00:00.000
76225   4546    14  2017-12-31 06:00:00.000 2017-12-31 08:30:00.000
76230   4546    15  2017-12-31 06:00:00.000 2017-12-31 08:30:00.000
76229   4546    14  2017-12-31 08:30:00.000 2018-01-01 06:00:00.000
```

Comment: Can you post a sample required output from your sample input? If I understand correctly, Plants 1 & 2 on daycode 1 were overlapping for 6 hours, right?

Comment: The output required is total monthly hours or days where one or two plants are available. For example as you mentioned in daycode 1 the overlap is 6 hours so there was one or two plants available for the rest of the day so the output shall be 18 hours.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question is your're trying to learn how many hours at least one plant was running during a specific month. It's easier to count total gap and then just subtract total number of hours to get the number your're looking for. Please see if example bellow is helpful.

**EDIT:** Added `HAVING COUNT(*) = @countOfPlants` to only look at days that have shutdowns for all plants. That should fix the issue first version had. Please let me know if that helped.

```
DECLARE
    @year INT = 2017,
    @month INT = 3,
    @countOfPlants int = 2,
    @totalGapInHours INT,
    @totalUptime INT

WITH InactivePerDay (DayCode, HoursBothPlantsShutdown)
AS
(
SELECT
    DayCode,
    -- take latest Shutdown_Start and earliest Shutdown_End that day
    -- get hour difference, if it's less than 0 - we have no gap - take 0
    MAX(DATEDIFF(HOUR, MAX(Shutdown_Start), MIN(Shutdown_End)), 0) AS [HoursBothPlantsShutdown]
FROM Table1
-- filter on the month you want
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, Shutdown_Start) = @year
AND DATEPART(MONTH, Shutdown_Start) = @month
GROUP BY DayCode
HAVING COUNT(*) = @countOfPlants
)
-- just sum up all the gaps
SELECT @totalGapInHours = SUM(HoursBothPlantsShutdown)
FROM InactivePerDay

-- assume month has 30 days and substract total gap from number of hours in a month
SET @totalUptime = 24*30 - @totalGapInHours
SELECT @totalUptime AS [Total hours at least one plant was running]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Only one issue with the above quey is that the MAX functions requires only one argument in the below line:  
    MAX(DATEDIFF(HOUR, MAX(Shutdown_Start), MIN(Shutdown_End)), 0) AS [HoursBothPlantsShutdown]

Comment: I will change this MAX function to be CASE

Comment: It is not giving me correct values because in days where only one plant is shutdown the gap is 24 while it should be zero. It

Comment: I really appreciate your follow up. It is still not showing correct figures. I am missing something. Let me show you some actual data so you can understand me better. I will show them in my question because no space here.